# RubyOnRails - How to model User being a Candidate or a Company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I tried to put the title the best I could.

Anyway,

In the website I'm trying to make a user can register and choose between being a company or a candidate. But it's not a question of roles. Because a company has some shared attributes with candidate but not all. Candidate and Company have attributes of their own.

I'm not sure how I should Model my Classes.

I mean belongs_to and has_one don't sound right to me.

I'm really on a stump. I tried the gem active_record-acts_as but I dont know how to approach controller methods and register forms with it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit more? Maybe explain what the purpose of each model is, or show how the models are defined? What do you mean by "doesn't feel right"? Does having those associations make the code work?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect case to use single table inheritance (STI). It basically allows you to use object inheritance in your models (more about STI [here](http://thibaultdenizet.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) or [here](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)).

You want to create class User that contains all attributes shared between Candidate and Company, then create Company and Candidate classes derived from User and add only attributes that are specific for those classes.